# Как в программе включить микрофон на Андроид устройстве?

Tags: java, android

```
    AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    audioManager.setMicrophoneMute(false);
    tv1.setText("Микрофон: "+audioManager.isMicrophoneMute());
```

Выдает - "Микрофон: true"

Answer (score 1):

Вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9409595/3212712) пишут что это частая проблема и её решают грязным хаком эмулирования нажатия на кнопку `Mute` на гарнитуре:

```
Intent buttonUp = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
buttonUp.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT,new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP,KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK));
getBaseContext().sendOrderedBroadcast(buttonUp,"android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED");
```

Comment: Это я видел, конечно. Не работает. Результат тот же: "Микрофон: true" :(

Comment: Не думаю, что готовые программы (к примеру диктофоны) будут использовать грязные хаки эмулирования нажатия!

Comment: @ЛЕО может Вам тогда открыть любой open source проект и посмотреть как там это реализовано? Расскажите тут заодно как правильно это реализовывать если не эмулированием